# Email Verification link not working when clicked, but works when pasting the link url itself

Tags: hyperlink, click, html-email, email-client, email-verification

I have a verification email that is sent out to users that sign up for a website I have developed. When the user signs up I send them an HTML email that has an anchor tag (hyperlink) `<a href="https://app.example.com/verify-email/akdios-aksdjofs-aisodfjsa" >Activate Account</a>`.
I believe this is a URL/href problem because if you click on the link it only takes you to the site `https://app.example.com`. Whereas if you paste the link in the browser then the proper verification page is loaded and the account is verified.

Email clients tested: outlook, (and various work email domains.).
What would be causing my link to not work when clicked, but works when I copy the link in the email, then paste it into the browser url?
Is there a way to ensure that clicking the link will work no matter what the email client (specifically outlook has been giving trouble).

Comment: Can you try this scenario: click once, and then go back and click again?

Comment: Also can you try to change your default browser, and try clicking again?

Comment: Both of those suggestions have been tested and found not working. We've tried 5 common browsers (Edge, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, internet Explorer), and found that this isn't browser specific. In fact it seems to be only email client specific (only some email clients will this not work for). Clicking n amount of times, doesn't work either. Simply the user is forced to copy the link and paste it in if their email client doesn't work by clicking it. Currently Outlook is the only client we know of that doesn't work on occasion for our users (specifically work mail).

Comment: Can you triple check each URL character, that's its the right character and not some similar looking variation?

Comment: As I already mentioned if you copy the link and past it, it works. If you click the link it doesn't......As you saw above the link is not in text form so you have to right click and select "copy link" then paste the link into your address bar. So it can be guaranteed that the link doesn't have similar looking characters in it. This seems to be an outlook problem (more common with work email).

Comment: Without getting more details of the actual setup, I can't help further. There's no fundamental issue with email and links. Perhaps if it's a work issue there's some sort of work-related addon in Outlook or the browser - some sort of security/phishing addon?